# What is the best way to simulate java.lang.Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, interpreter, bytecode, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm developing the transformer for **Java 6<sup>*1)</sup>** that performs a kind of *partial evaluation* but let's consider, for simplicity, *abstract-syntax-tree interpretation* of a Java program.

How to simulate the `Thread`'s behavior by an interpreted program?

At the moment I have in mind the following:

*AstInterpreter* should implement `java.lang.Runnable`. It also should rewrite every new-instance-expression of the `java.lang.Thread` (or its sub-class) replacing the `Thread`'s target (`java.lang.Runnable`) with  the new *AstInterpreter* instance:

**EDIT: more complex examples provided.**

**EDIT 2: remark 1.**

Target program:

```
class PrintDemo {
   public void printCount(){
    try {
         for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Counter   ---   "  + i );
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Thread  interrupted.");
     }
   }
}

class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;
   PrintDemo  PD;

   ThreadDemo( String name,  PrintDemo pd){
       threadName = name;
       PD = pd;
   }
   public void run() {
     synchronized(PD) {
        PD.printCount();
     }
     System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
   }

   public void start ()
   {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null)
      {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }
}

public class TestThread {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      PrintDemo PD = new PrintDemo();

      ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread - 1 ", PD );
      ThreadDemo T2 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread - 2 ", PD );

      T1.start();
      T2.start();

      // wait for threads to end
      try {
         T1.join();
         T2.join();
      } catch( Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Interrupted");
      }
   }
}
```

program 1 (ThreadTest - bytecode interpreted):

```
new Thread( new Runnable() {
   public void run(){
      ThreadTest.main(new String[0]);
   }
});
```

program 2 (ThreadTest - AST interpreted):

```
final com.sun.source.tree.Tree tree = parse("ThreadTest.java");

new Thread( new AstInterpreter() {
   public void run(){
      interpret( tree );
   }

   public void interpret(com.sun.source.tree.Tree javaExpression){
   //...  

   }
});
```

Does the resulting **program 2** simulate the Thread's behavior of the initial **program 1** correctly?

<sup>1)</sup> Currently, `source=8 / target=8` scheme is accepted.

Comment: Yes, you can write your own class that implements Runnable and that Runnable class can be run inside a Thread.  I fail to see what your AstInterpreter class does that a new Runnable can't.

Comment: why are you running on Java 6? There's no reason. All of your "Java 6" code will run, unmodified, on Java 7 and 8.

Comment: I'm indeed running under java 6. I've limited transformer by java 6 features and thus forced to use sdk6 because of langtools API.

Comment: So if I understand this right you want to build something like a doityourself JIT compiler? Kind of take a .java from anywhere and execute it?

Comment: @dryman - Not from anywhere - from classpath. I meant that the `ThreadTest` is executed in **program1** in the standard way (compiled in bytecode etc.)and in **program2** it is executed via ast-interpreter, e.g. similar to BeanShell or DynamicJava.

Comment: There are some (lots of, I guess) MT programs which would block being translated to ST, at least, in some particular end forms. Example: 2-threads producer-consumer pattern via limited blocking queue (`ArrayBlockingQueue`).

Comment: Are you only interested in partial evalution, or are you trying to really build an interpreter?  What is the specific goal of your project?

Comment: My goal is to build source-to-source specializer of Java programs.

Comment: By "specializer", do you mean a program that takes Java as input and evaluates those expressions whose value is known at compile time? In that case I think you don't have to run or simulate threads, just treat every thread's body as yet another piece of code to partially evaluate. Or am I missing something?

Comment: My specializer performs the interpretation step, then analyzes program execution graph generalizing it if any to provide termination. In principle, I think, it should model threads  e.g. to "inline" redundant `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: If your "interpreter" is running the program by classic interpretation using concrete values, you are unlikely to get much information about "specialization" with the possible exception of constant folding.   This requires reasoning about the program symbolically.  Symbolic simulation is a special case.  Simulating runnables now has to simulate all possible interleavings as opposed to just one.   Other symbolic operations you can do will use static analysis to enable various optimizations of the code, taking advantage of those values you declare to be constant.  Interpretation is insufficient.

Comment: ... if you want to simplify away Runnables, I'd be tempted to look at lifting individual statements out of the code executed by the runnable, into the code location just before the Runnable was invoked.  If you can do that with every statement of the Runnable code, what is left is Runnable on the empty program, which can be eliminated, and poof, the Runnable disappears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see two options:

Option 1: JVM threads. Every time the interpreted program calls Thread.start you also call Thread.start and start another thread with another interpreter. This is simple, saves you from having to implement locks and other things, but you get less control.

Option 2: simulated threads. Similar to how multitasking is implemented on uniprocessors - using time slicing. You have to implement locks and sleeps in the interpreter, and track the simulated threads to know which threads are ready to run, which have finished, which are blocked, etc.

You can execute instructions of one thread until it blocks or some time elapses or some instruction count is reached, and then find another thread which may run now and switch to running that thread. In the context of operating systems this is called process scheduling - you may want to study this topic for inspiration.

Comment: In particular, without some kind of interleaving of execution, you *have not* modelled "Runnables" in your interpreter.    Sergej is right.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do partial evaluation sensibly using a classic interpreter that computes with actual values.  You need symbolic values.

For partial evaluation, what you want is to compute the symbolic program state at each program point, and then simplify the program point based on the state known at that program point.  You start your partial evaluation process by writing down what you know about the state when the program starts.

If you decorated each program point with its full symbolic state and kept them all around at once, you'd run out of memory fast.   So a more practical approach is to enumerate all control flow paths through a method using a depth-first search along the control flow paths, computing symbolic state as you go.  When this search backtracks, it throws away the symbolic state for the last node on the current path being explored.  Now your saved state is linear in the size of the depth of the flow graph, which is often pretty shallow in a method.  (When a method calls another, just extend the control flow path to include the call).

To handle runnables, you have to model the interleavings of the computations in the separate runnables.  Interleaving the (enormous) state of two threads will get huge fast.  The one thing that might save you here is most state computed by a thread is completely local to that thread, thus is by definition invisible to another thread, and you don't have to worry about interleaving that part of the state.  So we are left with simulating interleaving of state seen by both two threads, along with simulation of the local states of each thread.

You can model this interleaving by implied but simulated parallel forks in the control flow: at each simulated step, either one thread makes one step progress, or the other (generalize to N threads).  What you get is a new state for each program point for each fork; the actual state for the program point is disjunction of the states generated by this process for each state.

You can simplify the actual state disjunction by taking "disjunctions" of properties of individual properties.  For instance, if you know that one thread sets x to a negative number at a particular program point, and another sets it to a positive number at that same point, you can summarize the state of x as "not zero".  You'll need a pretty rich type system to model possible value characterizations, or you can live with an impoverished one that computes disjunctions of properties of a variable conservatively as "don't know anything".

This scheme assumes that memory accesses are atomic.  They often aren't in real code so you sort of have to model that, too.  Probably best to have the interpreter simply complain your program has a race condition if  you end up with conflicting read and write operations to a memory location from two threads at the "same" step.  A race condition doesn't make your program wrong, but only really clever code use races in ways that aren't broken.

If this scheme is done right, when one thread A makes a call on a synchronous method on an object already in use by another thread B, you can stop interleaving A with B until B leaves the synchronous method.
If there is never interference between threads A and B over the same abstract object, you can remove the synchronized declaration from the object declaration.  I think this was your original goal

All this isn't easy to organize, and it is likely very expensive time/spacewise to run.   Trying to draw up an example of all this pretty laborious, so I won't do it here.

Model checkers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking do a very similar thing in terms of generating the "state space", and have similar time/space troubles.   If you want to know more about how to manage state do this, I'd read the literature on this.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. 
I don't use the classic interpreter in my transformer. It was mentioned just for simplicity.
I use "driving" (that is actually "abstract interpretation") among others techniques of so called "super-compilation".
It is experimental area (at least, beyond  the functional programming area) though it has the many in common with PE, deforestation, and some other well-known techniques.

Comment: Abstract interpretation: ok, so you *are* using a kind of symbolic simulation, good.   You should be able to do that along any control path, so the rest of the answer applies.  But it should be clear that using the Java interpreter itself to fork (Sergej's option 1) won't work.  My answer is an elabortion on Sergej's option 2 with emphasis on simulating the (potential) interleaving of the threads.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: It seems to me that using ReentrantLock's subclass, recording the acquiring threads' info, greatly reduces (or, even eliminates) the need in thread simulation. I replace standard lock with the mine one (both mentioned above) and replace `synchronized` statement with lock()/unlock() of my lock class. So, possibly I will have enough info about threads interference without extra effort.

Comment: The point of my answer was that running another thread would not help your symbolic interpretation, at least I don't see how.

Comment: Running new thread means running new symbolic interpreter instance, right?.. I may say I overestimated needlessness of concurrency simulation.

Comment: You might run a new, additional symbolic interpreter.  *But that won't model the effects of concurrency.*    You seem to be missing the point: you *have* to model the effects of possible interleavings, and two separate but parallel symbolic interpreters won't do that; they'd have to cooperate to do this.  Parallel threads probably don't make this modelling easier; your symbolic interpreter is likely better off simulating the concurrency as I described.